# Can I use JavaScript Variables inside a Django Project

Tags: javascript, django, django-staticfiles

I have written some JavaScript Code for my Django Project.

`

```
let current_theme = 0;
 
function darkmode() {
    if (current_theme == 0) {
        document.body.classList.add("darkmode")
        current_theme = 1;
    }
    else if (current_theme == 1) {
        document.body.classList.remove("darkmode")
        current_theme = 0;
    }
}
 
function switchMode() {
    if (current_theme == 0) {
        document.body.classList.add("darkmode")
        current_theme = 1;
        const lightModeBox = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
        lightModeBox.classList.remove("show");
    }
    else if (current_theme == 1) {
        document.body.classList.remove("darkmode")
        current_theme = 0;
        const lightModeBox = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
        lightModeBox.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
```

`

When I start the project (python manage.py runserver) and I go into the DevTools it says:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYjgS.png)
When I click on the first link it doesn't show the declaration of the Variable.
[Error JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRG89.png)

I tried declerate the Variable inside the function, but that doesn't work.
How else can I implement this?
Thank you :)

Comment: You don’t seem to have `let currenttheme = 0` in your actual js code.

Comment: Yes I just found the problem. The JavaScript Code wasn't the same so I made Hard Reload. That solved the problem. Thanks!